# C++ network interface invalid result

Tags: c++, c++11

First of all , Actually i am java developer and this code maybe unclear for C++ developers , sorry ....

I try to get network interface informations with native C++ Programming.
This is my example code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <netdb.h>
#include <ifaddrs.h>
#include <net/if.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/if_link.h>
#include <linux/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <list>

using namespace std ;

class Network {
private:
    struct ifaddrs *ifaddrs ;
    char host[NI_MAXHOST];

public:
    Network() {
        if (getifaddrs(&ifaddrs) == -1) {
            perror("getifaddrs");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    ~Network() {
        freeifaddrs(ifaddrs);
    }

    list<string> interfaces() {
        list<string> names ;
        for (struct  ifaddrs *ifa = ifaddrs ; ifa != NULL ; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
        {
            if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL) continue ;
            if (ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_PACKET) {
                names.push_back(ifa->ifa_name);
            }
        }
        return names ;
    }

    int mac_addr(const char *name,char *mac_addr) {
        int s;
        struct ifreq buffer;

        s = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
        memset(&buffer, 0x00, sizeof(buffer));
        strcpy(buffer.ifr_name, name);
        ioctl(s, SIOCGIFHWADDR, &buffer);
        close(s);

        char *data = buffer.ifr_hwaddr.sa_data;
        sprintf(mac_addr,
                "%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x:%02x",
                (unsigned char)data[0],
                (unsigned char)data[1],
                (unsigned char)data[2],
                (unsigned char)data[3],
                (unsigned char)data[4],
                (unsigned char)data[5]);
        return 0 ;
    }

    int ipaddr(const char *name, bool ipv4,bool netmask,char *ip) {
        void * tmpAddrPtr;

        for (struct  ifaddrs *ifa = ifaddrs ; ifa != NULL ; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
        {
            if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL) continue ;
            int family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family ;

            if (strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,name) == 0 && family == AF_INET && ipv4) {
                tmpAddrPtr = netmask ?
                             &((struct sockaddr_in *)(ifa->ifa_netmask))->sin_addr :
                             &((struct sockaddr_in *)(ifa->ifa_addr))->sin_addr ;
                inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
                return 0 ;
            } else if (strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,name) == 0 && family == AF_INET6 && !ipv4) {
                tmpAddrPtr = netmask ?
                             &((struct sockaddr_in *)(ifa->ifa_netmask))->sin_addr :
                             &((struct sockaddr_in *)(ifa->ifa_addr))->sin_addr ;

                inet_ntop(AF_INET6, tmpAddrPtr, ip, INET6_ADDRSTRLEN);
                return 0 ;
            }
        }
        return 1 ;
    }


    int link_stats(const char *name,struct rtnl_link_stats *stats) {
        for (struct  ifaddrs *ifa = ifaddrs ; ifa != NULL ; ifa = ifa->ifa_next)
        {
            if (ifa->ifa_addr == NULL) continue ;
            int family = ifa->ifa_addr->sa_family ;

            if (strcmp(ifa->ifa_name,name) == 0 && family == AF_PACKET && ifa->ifa_data != NULL) {
                stats = (struct rtnl_link_stats *) ifa->ifa_data;
                return 0 ;
            }
        }
        return 1 ;
    }
} ;


int main() {

    Network network ;
    list<string> interface_list = network.interfaces() ;
    list<string>::iterator it ;

    const char* ethernet = "wlan0" ; 
    char *ip = new char[16] ;
    struct rtnl_link_stats *stats ;

 
    network.ipaddr(ethernet,true,false,ip) ;
    network.link_stats(ethernet,stats) ;

    cout << "Ethernet Name: " << ethernet << endl ;
    cout << "Ethernet IP: " << ip << endl ;
    
    printf("\t\ttx_packets = %10u; rx_packets = %10u\n"
                          "\t\ttx_bytes   = %10u; rx_bytes   = %10u\n",
                          stats->tx_packets, stats->rx_packets,
                          stats->tx_bytes, stats->rx_bytes);
    free(ip);
    return 0;
}
```

**First Question :**
Why this code some times result Segmentation fault ?!

```
> make
mkdir -p build
c++ -g -o build/main main.cpp
strip --strip-all build/main
--------------------------------------------------------
> ./build/main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ./build/main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
> ./build/main
Ethernet Name: wlan0
Ethernet IP: 192.168.1.123
                tx_packets =          0; rx_packets = 4294967295
                tx_bytes   =      32615; rx_bytes   =  495411392
> ./build/main
Ethernet Name: wlan0
Ethernet IP: 192.168.1.123
                tx_packets = 3077881989; rx_packets =  818185032
                tx_bytes   =  609520456; rx_bytes   =    5081928
> ./build/main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

**Second Quesion :**
Why result is unstable ?!
for example tx_bytes some times return `32615` or `609520456` or ... .

Comment: There is no such language as "c/c++" your code is c++, please don't tag c in c++ questions

Comment: Further, unless your question is *specifically* in regard to features or problems related to specific versions of the language (c++11 for example), don't splay version-specific tags either. If it's a C++ question in-general, jus use the `c++` tag. As far as the posted code, fyi, you 'use' the `std::string` type (apparently) but don't include `<string>`. It's mandated by the standard, and should be included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why the segfault?

```
int ipaddr(const char *name, bool ipv4,bool netmask,char *ip) {
    ...
    inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, ip, INET_ADDRSTRLEN);

...

int main() {

    char *ip;

    network.ipaddr(ethernet,true,false,ip) ;
```

You are using an uninitialised pointer `ip` right there.

I would fix it like this

Change `ip` to be a `string`

```
string ip;
```

Change `ipaddr` to take that parameter by reference

```
int ipaddr(const char *name, bool ipv4,bool netmask,string& ip) {
```

Resize the string to the correct size immediately prior to calling `inet_ntop` and then use `string::data` to get the pointer `inet_top` requires.

```
ip.resize(INET_ADDRSTRLEN);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, tmpAddrPtr, ip.data(), INET_ADDRSTRLEN)
```

Similar change for the other call to `inet_top`

Good rule of thumb for C++ programs which have to interact with C API is to always hold your data in C++ objects (string, vectors etc) and convert to the pointers that the C API requires only at the point where you call the C API.

Comment: I update code and question and still receive segfault .

Comment: @mah454 There are still bugs, here's one `char *ip = new char[16] ;` and `free(ip);` Should be `delete[] ip`. There might be more.

Comment: @mah454 Here's another, `int link_stats(const char *name,struct rtnl_link_stats *stats) {` should be `int link_stats(const char *name,struct rtnl_link_stats *& stats) {` See the extra `&`? Very important to return the pointer assigned in the function to the calling function.